# what are name lookup rules within the hypothetical declaration that required in some contexts

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Issues 1:

```cpp
int v = 10;
auto f = [v = v](){};
```

Consider the above code,some rules mentioned in the standard will work for it.

[[expr.prim.lambda.capture#6]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.prim.lambda.capture#6)

> An init-capture behaves as if it declares and explicitly captures a variable of the form “auto init-capture ;” whose declarative region is the lambda-expression's compound-statement.

The quote means that `auto v = v;` would be declared in the lambda's compound-statement as if it like this:

```cpp
//hypothetical code
int v = 10;
auto f = [](){
  auto v = v;  //the second `v` is the first `v` and will be initialized by an indetermined value.
};
```

So,For the hypothetical declaration `auto v = v;`,I think it will conflict with the following rules.

[[basic.scope.pdecl#1]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.scope.pdecl#1)

> The point of declaration for a name is immediately after its complete declarator and before its initializer (if any)  [ Example:
>   *unsigned char x = 12;*
>   *{ unsigned char x = x; }*
>   Here the second x is initialized with its own (indeterminate) value.  — end example ]

Issue 2:

```cpp
void func(int v){}  
int v = 0;  
func(v);
```

We know the initialization of the function's parameter will occur within the context of the calling function and it will be copy-initialization.We ignore the quotes in the standard,because they are too much.So the copy-initialization of parameter will appear in somewhere within the context of the calling function as if it likes such form:

```cpp
//hypothetical code
int v = v; // initialization of a parameter that occured in somewhere within context of calling function
```

The same issue like **issue 1**,how to interpret these issues when the name of the declarator-id is the same as that of the  id-expression that within a initializer when they occured in these **hypothetical copy-initialization contexts**.Does these hypothetical copy-initializations contradict with the rule **[basic.scope.pdecl#1]**

#### Question:

I wonder that Is the lookup for the id-expression within initializer preceded than the hypothetical declaration occures? why do I think so? because, as the opposite, During the usual declaration, the lookup for initializer occures after the declarator immediately complete, as said in **[basic.scope.pdecl#1]**, It means the declarator-id would hide the id-expression that within the initializer if they are the same name.

Is there any quote in the standard interpret this?

Comment: When the text says `as if`, you shouldn't substitute in arbitrary syntax (even if it's the syntax that is closest in meaning), and then say that the syntax rules prohibit that substitution.

Comment: @cigien You mean that these hypothetical copy-initialization do not constract by [basic.scope.pdecl#1] rules and **the lookup for id-expression that appear within initializer is preceded than that for declarator-id**?

Comment: No, I mean `auto f = [v = v](){};` --> `auto f = [](){ auto v = v; }; ` is not a transformation that I think is valid. There are possibly no rules that let you do something like this.

Comment: @cigien The program itself is invalid,It just a hypothetical code and the rules in my question say that `as if...`.So,I wonder how it solve the name lookup for these hypothetical copy-initialization when `as if` occurs.In other words.For `auto f = [v = v](){};`, Is the lookup for the second `v` preceded than that for the first?

Answer (score 1):

`initializer` in [basic.scope.pdecl] refers to an element of a grammar rule, that is used by the parser. It is defined in [[dlc.init]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init#nt:initializer) and it appears in the [`init-declarator`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.decl#nt:init-declarator) grammar rule.

For the case of the lambda capture, the standard specifies that it is equivalent to an init-declarator **but** *whose declarative region is the lambda-expression's compound-statement[...]* that is, the capture name is not in the scope of the initializer.

The term `initialization` does not refer to the grammar rule referred by the term `initilizer`. `initialization` is an expression evaluation that initialize a variable, this is not a grammar rule. The rules which involve those two terms cannot conflict because they are not part of the same phase of the compilation->execution process:

1) The grammar rules for `initializer`, `declarator`, or `init-caputure`, etc... are used to determine to which object refers an id-expression (a name within an expression) that appears within an initializer. An id-expression is a glvalue. A glvalue referes to an object, and it has no name.

2) Then those glvalues are parts of the expression that perform `initialization`. When this initialization takes place, names are irrelevant.

NB: In the standard, many rules referrers to grammar rules and you should take care of the formatting to recognize them, because their name has no more sense in itself than the name of a variables that appear inside mathematical equations.

Comment: you have not interpter how the name within initializer be found by name lookup rules in the hypothetical declatation that defined in lambda's compound-statement. :-)

Comment: @jackX ... The sentence "[the capture] declarative region is the lambda-expression's compound-statement"  means the capture can only be found by name look only within the function body of the lambda-closure call operator: only between the { and }.

Comment: excatly, the variable declared within the function body only can be found in that scope, the non-static data member is another way refer to the same entity. I mean that within "auto init-capture ;" which is declared in function body,the initializer, namely the variable in lambda's reaching scope,  how to find the name  when it appears after the captured variable?

Comment: Maybe the description is not clear. For example `int a = 0; void function(){ int a = a;}`, There's a declaration within function's body, that is  `int a = a;`, the first `a` within the declaration will be as the looked up name for the second `a` within the initializer, not the `a` outside the function. So, the `auto init-capture ;` that would be declared within lambda's compound statement is the same case as I write in the above. I wonder how the name lookup work to find the name for initializer within the  `auto init-capture ;`

Comment: --- i.e. the variable would be initialized by an indetermine value if the name within the initializer be lookup according to the unqualifed name lookup rules

Comment: @jackX But the variable is not declared inside the function body. A variable name scope is just an area of the source code where a name that is the same as the variable name denote that variable. Actualy [v=v](){} is equivalent to [this code](https://godbolt.org/z/i6TqP2)

Comment: @jackX I think you should start to read [basic](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic) slowly first, without trying to burn the steps. And the standard is supposed to be read by someone who is actualy coding a compiler. It is just a spaghetti compiler algorithm that as been written litteraly with some tentative to find abstract concept that could simplify the text. "Scope" is one of those concepts. Most of those abstractions appears in the first line of [basic] so read it carefully.

Comment: "An init-capture behaves as if it declares and explicitly captures a variable of the form “auto init-capture ;” whose declarative region is the lambda-expression's compound-statement." means the declatation "auto init-capture ;" will be declared in the lambda's compound-statement, namely within {}, I think I don't misread about this sentence.

Comment: @JackX So you decided not to read the preposition that start with "whose"... Last trial:"An init-capture behaves as if it declares and explicitly captures a variable of the form “auto init-capture ;".

Comment: NEVERTHELESS the declarative region of this declaration does not start just after the name but at the beginning of the lambda-expression's compound-statement.

Comment: "Whose" refer to  "a variable of the form “auto init-capture ;” ", I don't understand what your reading about this sentence. My understanding about it is the variable of the form “auto init-capture ;”  as if it is declared within the lambda-expression's  compound-statament where is the declartive region of the variable.

Comment: @jackX It is said nowhere: "Whose" refer to a declaration, not a variable. The declaration is the init-capture. A declaration introduce a name. In this case the name is introduced within the lambda-compound statement. But the declaration is not within the compound statement.

Comment: you mean that the intent of that sentence is, the variable name can be found in the lambda-compound statement? I think it's not all, otherwise, it's no necessary to add an additional rule "if the capture is by copy... and no additional copy and destruction is performed", if there's no this rule, then the variable be declared in the declaration would have automatic duration storage, hence I think the intent of that sentence is , a hypothetical declaration , namely "auto init-capture ;" as if it would be declared in the lambda's compound-statement. and any associate rules would be apply on it-

Comment: -- except what the additional rule says

Comment: @jackX Actually, it look like from the `auto init-caputure` only the initialization rules are kepts: whither it is a value initialization, direct, list-initialization, copy/or direct initialization etc... Any thing related to the declaration or life-duration is replaced by the exception and the preposition that begin by `whose`. I think this is a good idea, because the semantic of initializers is just huge!!

Comment: I have to say this sentence is unclear, because the exception only include such as lifetime and copy, destruction, there's no more. I think the intent of this sentence is, through the hypothetical declaration, some rules associate with declarations can be applied on  the it, such as the scope of variable's name. as you said, the semantic of initializer is so huge, however it's a part of an declaration(if any), hence I think such as unqualified name lookup rule, name hidden etc. But these rules that do not appropriate with the hypothetical declaration, have not listed in the exception.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215075/discussion-between-jack-x-and-oliv).